# cmd ask user for multiple input with different action

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

i just try to make mini-dos that will do different action for each output. here is what i wanted:
if user type ? then it will type this:

```
"del for delete.(you will get to type the file name later.)"
"edit for text editor."
"remoteshutdown for remote shutdown(Real) computer."
"note for mickywachi's note"
```

it work perfectly but if i type del, edit, remoteshutdown, note and other stuff it will do the same!
what i want the del to do:

```
Type in file you want to delete!

(input for file name)
```

then it will delete that file and ask for input again.
what i wanted edit to do is to open an extra program. same with remoteshutdown and note.
and what i wanted it to do when user type in wrong command:

```
(username they logged on), you typed in the wrong command! type ? for help.
```

and it will ask for input again.
can anyone help? here is the code(skip that big text and login and go to label input. that is where the problem are.)

```
@echo off

title miOS

color 12

echo "-------------------------"
echo "           _  ___  ____  "
echo " _ __ ___ (_)/ _ \/ ___| " 
echo "| '_ ` _ \| | | | \___ \ "
echo "| | | | | | | |_| |___) |"
echo "|_| |_| |_|_|\___/|____/ "
echo "-------------------------"

echo Copyright(C)mickywachi. All rights Reserved.

pause

cls

color f0
echo Starting miOS....
set current=%CD%
echo Please Login.

:login

color f0
set /p username=Username: 

if %username%==Administrator goto passlogin

if %username%==mickywachi goto passlogin else {
    color f4
    echo Wrong User!
    pause
    goto :login
}

:passlogin

color f0
set /p password=Password: 
if %username% == Administrator if %password%==admin goto logon

if %username% == mickywachi if %password%==micky1594 goto logon else {
    color f4
    echo Wrong Password!
    pause
    goto :passlogin
}

:logon

echo Welcome to miOS!
echo Type ? for help.

:input

set /p input=%current%: 

if %input%==? {
    echo "del for delete.(you will get to type the file name later.)"
    echo "edit for text editor."
    echo "remoteshutdown for remote shutdown(Real) computer."
    echo "note for mickywachi's note"

    set input=/
    goto input
}

if %input%==del {
    echo Type in file name you want to delete!

    set /p delwhat=: 
    del %current%\%delwhat%.mifile
    set input=/

    goto input
}

if %input%==remoteshutdown start REMOTESHUTDOWN.bat

if %input%==note start mickywachiNote.bat else {
    echo %username%, You typed in wrong command! type ? for help.
    set input=/

    goto input
}
```

anyone got idea for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional action-statments must be surrounded with round brackets `(   )` not braces `{   }`

There is no choice here.

Comment: thank you, it work now. but with the one with note it open the note and do else at the same time! edit:nevermind, it work now

Comment: batch has no way of knowing whether the `else` is a command-parameter for `start` or is an `else` conditional. You need to use `if ... (start whatever) else (somethingelse)` that is, the instruction to execute on true should be `(parenthesised)`